# Android. Скрытая кнопка, пока поля не заполнены

Tags: android, button, hide

Хотел бы узнать, как можно скрывать кнопку до тех пор, пока поля не заполнены. Например, у нас есть одна кнопка, и три EditText, кнопку будет не видно, пока все 3 EditText не заполнены.

Comment: можно поставить слушателей на изменение текста в editText и отслеживать заполнение, когда все три будут заполнены отображаешь кнопку

Comment: @Nikotin можешь написать реализацию, а то вообще догнать не могу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я сделал пример, который на мой взгляд будет проще поддерживать в проектах.

Здесь нет ограничения, в кол-ве EditText, хотя я для примера использовал три, как у вас в вопросе.

### MultiEditText.class

```
public class MultiEditText extends AppCompatActivity{

EditText ed_1, ed_2, ed_3;
Button btn_ok;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.multi_edit_text);

    ed_1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed_1);
    ed_2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed_2);
    ed_3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed_3);
    btn_ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_ok);
    btn_ok.setEnabled(false);

    //Если EditText значительно больше, можно добавить цикл и List interface
```

> ```
>     EditText[] edList = {ed_1, ed_2, ed_3};
>     CustomTextWatcher textWatcher = new CustomTextWatcher(edList, btn_ok);
>     for (EditText editText : edList) editText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
> ```

```
    }
}
```

Выглядит просто, и намного короче правда?)
Теперь...

### CustomTextWatcher.class

```
public class CustomTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

View v;
EditText[] edList;

public CustomTextWatcher(EditText[] edList, Button v) {
    this.v = v;
    this.edList = edList;
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    for (EditText editText : edList) {
        if (editText.getText().toString().trim().length() <= 0) {
            v.setEnabled(false);
            break;
        }
        else v.setEnabled(true);
    }
  }
}
```

Я добавил разметку, чтоб вам не тратить время.

### multi_edit_text.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="16dp">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ed_1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ed_2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ed_1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ed_3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ed_2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_ok"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ed_3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="OK" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Например так:

```
EditText et1,et2,et3;
Boolean ready1,ready2,ready3;
Button btn;

btn.setVisibility(View.GONE); // hide view
 et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if(s.length() == 0)
           ready1 = false;
        else  ready1 = true; 
        checkReady();

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
});

et2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if(s.length() == 0)
           ready2 = false;
        else  ready2 = true; 
        checkReady();

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
});

et3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if(s.length() == 0)
           ready3 = false;
        else  ready3 = true; 
        checkReady();

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
});

void checkReady(){
    if(ready1 && ready2 && ready3)
         btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBILITY);
     else btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Устанавливаете слушатель на свои textView, в какую то переменную записуете состояние(сколько textView щас заполнены)  создаете условие и если оно выполняется - то показываете кнопку.

```
 boolean isAllFill = false;
 mButton.setVisibility(View.GONE); // hide view
 mTextView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            //check isAllFill and show button
            if(isAllFill){
                mButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //show view
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```